# Автоподключение к БД (hibernate+mysql)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, persistance

Добрый день!

В настройках БД устанновленно "wait_timeout=60". Если к БД не обращаться в течении 60сек, то коннект пропадает. Как настроить приложение, чтобы оно чекало БД и либо автоматом переподлючалось, либо обращалось к БД каждые n-сек, не давая ей отвалиться? Менять wait_timeout на 0 не могу, т.к. дпелоить буду на heroku, а там на БД, стоит опция автоотключения.

Использую *MySQL+Hibernate+Tomcat*.
Мой persistance.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="FlatsJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apartments_db?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="0"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="51"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="51"/>-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: попробуй `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes`

Comment: `autoReconnect=true` тут точно все латинские символы?

Comment: `autoReconnect=true` - все символы латинские (проверил)

Comment: `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes` и `?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes;` выдает ошибку `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 135; The reference to entity "useUnicode" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

Comment: спасибо, помогла следующая запись: `?autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;interactiveClient=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` осталось разобраться какой проперти здесь за что отвечает.

Comment: Что конкретно ?

Comment: `autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;inter‌​activeClient=true` - вот эти два.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из комментариев выяснилось, что нужно было добавить

```
autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;inter‌​activeClient=true
```